# Cannot open database "[Database]" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user '[User]"

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I'm getting the above error when using EF code first. Everything works as expected when running my code for the first time, but when I delete my database and run the code again the exception is thrown. It seems like EF is not creating the database the second time around and seems to thinks the database still exists.

When I reset iis, EF is able to create the database again (Only the first time).

Here is my connection string

```
<add name="DatabaseContext" connectionString="Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=UnitTest;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=MyUser;Password=MyPassword"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: So after the application is deployed in the IIS somehow, somebody will drop the database, and you expect that EF will automatically re-create the database again without restarting the IIS?

Comment: Just remove the `Persist Security Info=True;` from your connection string. That might resolve your problem.

Comment: @YuliamChandra This exception also occur when just testing from my local machine without deploying to iis

Comment: @user65439, same thing, you run the application, application execute a query and will create the database if it doesn't exit, while the app is still running, **you drop the database**, and then execute the query again -> exception, right ?

Comment: @KrishnrajRana Unfortunately that did not solve the problem for me

Comment: @YuliamChandra From my local machine I execute the query that will create the database, stop the application, delete the database and run the application again which then throws the exception. It might be worth to mention that the code is run from a unit test

Comment: @YuliamChandra, sorry the service was still pointing to my development server which was not stopped. When correcting this the code worked as expected. I did not realize that EF will not be able to determine that the database was deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running the application, the first query execution will build a metadata model per application domain and each new `DbContext` will reuse the global metadata.

I'm afraid when you drop the database, the same application domain is still being used to execute the query, but EF still thinks that the database has been created because the metadata is cache globally. This kind of behavior is rarely happened.

But you can try to execute the database explicitly if it doesn't exist. This will create additional overhead to check the database existence every query execution.

```
using (var db = new AppContext())
{
    if (!db.Database.Exists())
    {
        db.Database.Initialize(true);
    }

    // query
}
```

Or you can put it in the constructor.